# Set UIImageView in background programmatically

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

i have a class with no .xib file, and i want to set the background with a UIImageView with a .png file i have in the resources, i try this:

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:background];
[background release];
```

this work, but the image is zoomed in and loses a lot of quality, instead in another class with xib file i set a UIImageView in background by Interface Builder  and the image is perfetct, i wanna know how i can set the UIImageView in background as i do in interface builder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry if i forgot to write that my class is a UITableViewController, this is the solution:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

thanks to all!

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a UIImageView subview instead of UIColor.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed.@"background.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView]; // edited for syntax
[imageView release];
```

Comment: i use it in my UITableViewController, and it works but i can't see anymore my row table...i use also this:[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:imageView];...but i can't see the row...

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

and if your image size is grater then 320x480 px then use septi's answer.

Comment: i use it in my UITableViewController, and it works but i can't see anymore my row table...i use also this:[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:imageView];...but i can't see the row...

Comment: where r u adding image in table's row or in your view?

Answer (score 2):

Just a little addition to the answers already provided

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

Comment: i use it in my UITableViewController, and it works but i can't see anymore my row table...i use also this:[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:imageView];...but i can't see the row...